# What is the most efficient way in Kotlin to check if values in two arrays don't differ by much?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I need to check if none of the values in two IntArray objects differ by more than 1.

This is the working code, which takes too long:

```
         var pixelOutsideOfTolerance = false
         val PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE = 1
            for (i in 0 until pixels1.lastIndex) {
                if (pixels1[i] - pixels2[i] > PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE && pixels1[i] - pixels2[i] < - PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE) {
                    pixelOutsideOfTolerance = true
                }
            }
         // Do something with pixelOutsideOfTolerance
```

What would be a more performant and eloquently way to do this?

Comment: You can `break` after setting `pixelOutsideOfTolerance` to true. Does that help?

Comment: Very valid. I just noticed that after positing...

Comment: On an unrelated side note, if these integers are (A)RGB pixel values, comparing the distances of their raw value would only consider differences in blue to be small. Having a difference of 1 in the reds would be inappropriately discarded as "outside tolerance" because it would be considered much higher

Comment: @Joffrey thanks, this is a very related comment and it came at the right time! I am trying to compare two screenshots (one by UIAutomation and one by the MediaProjection API) which by the naked eye look the same, but as bitmaps don't have the same pixel values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before fixing performance, you must ensure correctness:

- you have an off-by-one error because `lastIndex` is the actual last index, not the size. Use `for (i in pixels1.indices)` instead of explicit ranges to avoid this kind of mistakes
- your condition can never be true, because you're using `&&` instead of `||`. Use `abs(pixels1[i] - pixels2[i]) > PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE` instead of the more complicated condition checking both positive and negative, it will be simpler to read and less likely to get wrong (you'll need `import kotlin.math.abs`)

Now you're doing the whole loop even when you already know some pixel differences are outside the tolerance. Extract a function for this loop, and return early when the "outside tolerance" condition is met.

Applying the above, you should now have:

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.abs

private const val PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE = 1

private fun areSimilar(pixels1: IntArray, pixels2: IntArray): Boolean {
    for (i in pixels1.indices) {
        if (abs(pixels1[i] - pixels2[i]) > PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

// then just use
val pixelsOutsideOfTolerance = !areSimilar(pixels1, pixels2)
```

If performance was not a requirement, you could also use a more functional approach here. For instance:

```kotlin
val pixelsOutsideOfTolerance = pixels1.indices.any {
    abs(pixels1[it] - pixels2[it]) > PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE
}
```

Or:

```kotlin
val pixelsOutsideOfTolerance = pixels1.asSequence().zip(pixels2.asSequence())
    .any { abs(it.first - it.second) > PIXEL_VALUE_TOLERANCE }
```

But if it's really a hot path that you are trying to speed up, that will be counter-productive because of boxing.

Comment: It looks like I somehow overlooked many obvious things... But I guess the gist of my question was wether there was any other way of doing this instead of looping. But since I didn't make that clear in my question, I accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Crocodile if the operation you want to do is to compare all the pixels, you'll have to loop over the pixels. You can of course use a more functional approach, but it will likely be less performant due to boxing, which wouldn't be a good move if you have really identified that this is a hot path.

Comment: Why does the `.indices.any{ }` approach cause boxing?

Comment: I actually wrote the text about boxing before I added the version with `indices.any { ... }`. I think this still creates an iterator, although it's probably a non-boxing `IntIterator`. I wonder how much overhead the iterator would create compared to the for loop, maybe not so much